# How to handle dependencies between business objects

Tags: c#, .net

Apologies if this has been asked before, I can't find a similar question so I can only assume my terminology is wrong!

Anyway I'm wondering how to handle dependencies between business layer objects.  Say I have two business objects:

A Wheel Service

```
public class WheelService : IWheelService
{
    private IWheelRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public WheelService(IWheelRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }

    public Wheel Get(int id) { ... }
}
```

And a Car Service

```
public class CarService : ICarService
{
    private ICarRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public CarService(ICarRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }

    public void Create(Car newCar)
    {
        // I need to access functions from the WheelService here
    }
}
```

What sort of architecture would you use that would all me to call methods of one business object from another in a loosely coupled way that would also fit well with TDD?

Comment: Register the Services in your IoC and use Constructor Injection if no cyclic dependency is possible. Usually you cannot inject ServiceA to ServiceB and ServiceB to ServiceA at the same time. In this case you would need another service design or a third ServiceC that handles the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add them the same way you add your repository dependence in your constructor:

```
public CarService(ICarRepository repository, IWheelService wheelservice)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yea that's a fair point actually -  sometimes it's the simple things that you just can't see!

Comment: Do you do anything different if there are a large number of dependencies or would you say that point to over complexity of the service?

Comment: Over complexity is a smell, this means you have to many responsibilities in the service. Split them into different classes. Source code should be simple, not complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `Builder` pattern, which will be useful if you have many dependencies

```
public class CarService : ICarService
{
    private ICarRepository Repository { get; set; }
    private IWheelService WheelService { get; set; }

    public CarService(ICarRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }

    public ICarService WithWheelService(IWheelService service)
    {
        // do arguments check
        if(service == null) throw ...;

        WheelService = service;
        return this;
    }
    public Car Build()
    {
        return new Car(WheelService, ...);        
    }
}
```

Here is the usage

```
ICarService carService = new CarService();
IWheelService wheelService = new WheelService();
...    
carService.WithWheelService(wheelService)
          .WithSomethingElse(somethingElse)
          .WithLights(brightLights)
          .UsingMainColour(selectedColour);
var car = carService.Build()
```

See these lines

```
ICarService carService = new CarService();
IWheelService wheelService = new WheelService();
```

This is where you can use IoC container to resolve the needed classes.